# Delete and update api calls are not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I know this is basic knowledge but i am not able to crack it, Is there any wrong in api calls. i am not able get my results,
i tried everything but i am not able find any solution for this error.

```
exports.update =  (req, res) => {
        let value = (req.body)
        User.updateOne({ userid: req.params.id },{
            $set:{
                value
            },
        },{multi:true})
            .exec(function (error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    res.json("not done")
                }
                else {
                    res.json("done")
                }
            })
}

exports.delete =  (req, res) => {
        User.findOneAndRemove(req.params.id)
            .exec(function (error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    res.json("not done")
                    // res.json({ message: "User not found with userID" + value })
                }
                else {
                    res.json("done")
                    // res.json({ message: "user deleted with userID" + value })
                }
            })
};
```

and both api's are not working.
[image: i am getting this error message whenever i tried with both api calls.]

Comment: Post the code from where you are calling the `delete` function.

Comment: in this way it wil not work.?

Comment: I meant, you should update the answer with the full code. I believe the problem is not in the code you have provided.

Comment: Where are your routes defined? Specifically you must have defined them in `app.js` or `server.js` ..that you should update the question with

Comment: @ambianBeing I defined routes `save()` and `find()` are working fine

Comment: This code looks fine though. Only asked to update the code with defined routes to have more context and visibility on what might be going wrong here.

Comment: You must be messing something with the route as it clearly says `404`.

Comment: its solved, i meesed up something in routers, thanku you everyonr for your time

Answer (score 2):

```js
User.findOneAndRemove(req.params.id)
```

should be changed to

```js
User.findOneAndRemove({userId: req.params.id})
```

or to whatever your id sequencer is. Such as in typical mongoDB:

```js
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId

User.findOneAndRemove({_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)})
```